# How to create a reusable components that do not have the same props?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I am new to react and I am trying to create a reusable component. Below is the layout of the component.

```
 <TestLayout
          header={`©${year} Hello foo`}
          description={"test"}
          link={"link1"}
        />
        <TestLayout header={`©${year} Hello char }`} link={"link2"} />
```

```
const TestLayout = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{props.header}</p>
      <p>{props.link}</p>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestLayout;
```

As seen above, I did not pass the description prop on the second component to experiment with the output. I would like to know if this will cause any huge problems as the app scales larger.

Right now, there are no errors and the second component will just not display the description but what if I have multiple components that have different properties that need to be displayed, and not all of the components will have similar properties? How can I better structure my reusable component?

Comment: Please check how to ask the question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no its seems to be ok , just add condition to show description (because if the description is not passed, an empty p tag will be there ) like:  { props.description ? <p>{props.description}</p> : null }

Comment: You could wrap your output in conditional logic so that the `<p>` elements themselves aren't included in the output if the value isn't present.  But aside from that, what exactly are you asking?  It sounds like your code works.  If you're just looking for different ways to style your code, you are encouraged to test different approaches and see what you can find.